# file_exists() and mkdir($a, $b, true) do not work properly if my Apache runs in a VirtualBox and the DocumentRoot is a shared folder. Why?

Tags: virtualbox, apache-http-server, php, shared-folders, mkdir

I have a Windows7 PC with a hosted VirtualBox (Ubuntu). On the VirtualBox is an Apache2. The  is shared to the Windows7 host. So if I use 
ls -l 
I see that the contents are owned by root:vboxsf.

If I switch on the VirtualBox to the Apache user "www-data" (sudo su www-data) I am not able to use
mkdir -p /newfolder/newsubfolder

The following would work
mkdir /newfolder
mkdir /newfolder/newsubfolder

If I run a PHP-Script I have also trouble with mkdir() if the third parameter is true
mkdir("/newfolder/newsubfolder", 0774, true);

I have also a problem if I use a PHP-Script with file_exists(). The result is always true.

How do I have to configure the shared folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I add sth. like 
mount -t vboxfs htdocs /var/www -o uid=www-data,gid=www-data
to /etc/rc.local

htdocs is the name of the share in VirtualBox.